# Is Pixeluvo a good Photoshop alternative?

Tags: photo-editing, software-recommendation, linux

Photography is my hobby and I am a Linux user. By now, I almost did not edit my photos and used only RawTherapee to work with RAW files.

Sometimes I want to edit my photos and looking for an appropriate software. Photoshop is obvious the best photo editor, but it can't be run with Linux (virtual machine doesn't look an option for me because it will be slower than native running).

Pixeluvo seems to be an option, but I didn't found many reviews on it. Does it worth to be bought as Photoshop alternative?

Comment: I haven't used Pixeluvo so I'm not in a position to answer your exact question, but have you tried GIMP? Since it's free you lose nothing by trying it. Over the years I've used Photoshop Elements, Serif Photoplus, Paint Shop Pro, Coreldraw and a few others and I've always come back to GIMP as just objectivly better (in terms of output, I admit its UI is shonky) than anything that costs less than full Photoshop.

Comment: mmm looks like there's a trial version of Pixeluvo, which I'm rather tempted to give a go

Comment: @JosephRogers Yes, I tried GIMP, but Pixeluvo has features that GIMP doesn't (e.g. adjustment layers). As for trial, I tried it but it doesn't allow to save high resolution images. In general I wanted to know if there are any obvious thins that are absent in Pixeluvo.

Comment: Adjustment layers would be nice, I think I'll give the trial a look. I look forward to someone providing a comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

I think Pixeluvo is a great Alternative for GIMP, but not so for RAW Processing. Have you ever tried Darktable? It's one of the best RAW Tool for Linux & MAC. Darktable in Combination with Pixeluvo is my Dreamteam for Picturemanipulation & Processing.

Answer (score 1):

This anwer has a good chance to be voted down becouse I am not answering your question if it is a good alternative.

> Sometimes I want to edit my photos and looking for an appropriate software.

The thing is we do not know what you want to "edit", what you consider "appropriate" enough and what is your workflow.

"Editing" can go from just rotating a photo to make a complete new image out of several images. I sometimes even do "Photo editing" inside Corel Draw with vectors.

So one thing you need to ask yourself is what kind of editing you need and then you have some basis to compare and to search.

Do not waste your time analizing all the features of a program. Put specific objetives for example.

In a portrait. Do I have frecuency separation to smooth the skin? Can I mask easily the hair? Do I need some specific feature? Thoose kind of questions.

Then you will have a specific set of features YOU need.

Appropriate is relative too. Some people do not use gimp becouse its UI but probably the features are good enough. Sometimes "appropriate" is a program that has a box of filters or a specialized very specific feature.

Answer (score -1):

There are many "alternatives" which may be great for certain use cases but none at present have the combination of the workflow, features and stability that give Photoshop the market dominance it commands - even if you discounted the huge installed user base and collective knowledge of the photographic/arts community.

There are unlikely to be any for the foreseeable future as developing that kind of package takes a great deal of work.  It takes an army of software developers, researchers, UX engineers, and graphic designers, all of whom have bills to pay and families to feed.  Between the number of developers and the input/feedback they get from the industry there is no way any potential challenger could afford to compete with them.  Anyone who might be able to manage some intellectual leap would get bought up in a flash (hello Macromedia, pardon the pun.)  It would be like a new startup going toe to toe with Google and expecting not to get crushed like a bug.

**TL;DR** No, there isn't a viable alternative.